# Scanf Function And Integers

Tags: c, scanf

I know that when getting char one should be aware of it consuming white spaces too.

This is not the case in

> scanf("%d", &num)

But in the case of:

```
 case 2:
            printf("Please enter first number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            printf("Please enter second number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &num2);

            break;
```

If the user enters:

```
444    5
```

the first scanf gets 444 and the second gets 5, even those they did not press enter.
it there a way to get only one int and end the scanf if the user presses backspace?

Comment: yes, use `fgets` first then scan 1 value only

Comment: If you want to handle inputs like backspace, you need to read characters from the keyboard directly.    That is not possible with `scanf()` - or with standard C for that matter.    However, most compilers come with one or more vendor-specific functions that can read characters directly from the keyboard.  You will need to read documentation for your compiler, and any non-standard function bundled with it, to find those functions.

Comment: @Peter I would think that if you configure the terminal in the right way every character is directly available for `getc()`, so it's also a OS function.

Comment: `scanf()` is nice for education, not used so much in the real world.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - the methods/functions to configure the terminal that way are specific to some OSs.   Without that, `getc()` does not behave in the way you describe.   The fact that an OS can interact and change the behaviour of `getc()`, or any other function, doesn't make `getc()` an OS function.

Comment: @Hogstrom Well, scanf is a great tool -- re-inventing the wheel (by programming one's own parsers) is error-prone. What's unusual in the real world is *interactive terminal input.* Real-world programs other than editors and shells may scan command line parameters but then typically receive input from elsewhere (transparent to them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for this you could

- read the whole line using `fgets` for instance
- `sscanf` the line for only 1 integer

like this:

```
char buffer[80];
fgets(buffer, 80, stdout);
if (sscanf(buffer,"%d",&value) == 1)
{
   // scan succeeded
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
while ((getchar()) != '\n');
```

to wait until the "enter" key is pressed

```
 case 2:
            printf("Please enter first number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            while ((getchar()) != '\n');
            printf("Please enter second number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &num2);

        break;
```

Comment: Note, this will not detect empty input line followed by data `"\n"`, `"123\n"` yet accept like `"123\n"`.